# FreeBSD routing for multiple subnets

Tags: routing, freebsd

I have to access a network 10.1.0.0/16 through a gateway 10.4.0.2.
I issue the command:

```
route add -net 10.1.0.0/16 10.4.0.2
```

The machine's IP address where I doing this is 10.4.0.22 and it's default gateway is 10.4.0.1 so this is an alternate route to the 10.1.x.x network. Both gateways are reachable (10.4.0.1, 10.4.0.2) from this machine.

This works flawlessly on other Linux boxes, it does not on FreeBSD and I would like to know why. There are no firewalls configured at any point of the network, so that cannot be an issue.

Comment: How *exactly* does it not work??

Comment: Without knowing the specific symptoms of "does not work", it is pretty hard to make any kind of a real guess. In addition to that information, it might also be useful to include the results of "netstat -rn", so we can see the routing table (also available via "route show".